# My SQL Server logs are being flooded with successful logins

Tags: sql-server, logging

Pretty much what the title says. I've been working on tweaking one of my servers and getting things running more smoothly and had to peek into the error logs the other day. When I did, I noticed that they're absolutely chock-full of records of successful logins, mostly from either the user that's running the SQL service or from a user running a service on another machine that refreshes its connection a couple times a minute. (I do plan to look at that service to see if I can do something about how it's managing its connection, but that's a separate deal.) I don't want to turn off logging for these events entirely, but I'd like to explore options for separating them so I can chase down other issues without having to wade through them all. What's my best course of action here?

Comment: Your best course of action is oddly enough turning off logging for successful logins. It's unnecessary on most setups

Answer (score 1):

To make explicit @charlieface's recommendation above, here's a quick powershell script to change the audit level. It uses the excellent dbatools powershell module.

```
# use your instance name instead of '.'

$s = Connect-DbaInstance -SqlInstance .; 
$s.AuditLevel = 'Failure';
$s.Alter();
```

Valid values for the AuditLevel enum can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.auditlevel?view=sql-smo-160).